# How does one set up agent authentication on Zabbix?

Tags: authentication, zabbix

Apparently there is a way to add a username/password to zabbix_agentd.conf and zabbix_server.conf so that the sever can authenticate the agent and the agent can start sending monitoring data to the server.

The wiki pages I found provide a "patch" but don't really explain the process of how to use it or put authentication into place:

- https://zabbix.org/wiki/Active_agent_authentication
- https://zabbix.org/wiki/Active_agent_authentication_tech

Can someone please help me understand how to use this patch or implement authentication in a different way?

Comment: Have you gone through the documentation and having any issues with the implementation?

Comment: which documentation? please point me to it!

Answer (score 1):

What you're trying to do was never supported and is 7 years old.

I think what you want is encryption which has keys thus authentication. This feature was added in Zabbix v3.0 or v3.2. I don't recall exactly when but it was much later than v1.8 which you referenced in your question.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/encryption